# ¿Cómo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos en Java?

Tags: java, poo

¿De qué manera puedo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos pero sin usar bibliotecas o clases ya creadas por Java?

Comment: Por qué sin usar Clases o bibliotecas? estas hacen el trabajo más sencillo .

Answer (score 9):

> **¿De que manera puedo eliminar un objeto de un arreglo de objetos pero
> sin usar bibliotecas o clases ya creadas por Java?**

Hola Santiago, **sin usar bibliotecas** puedes tener varias opciones, por ejemplo:

```
  public static Object[] remueveElement(Object[] arrayObjetos, int i) {
      System.arraycopy(arrayObjetos, i + 1, objeto,i, arrayObjetos.length - 1 - i);
      return arrayObjetos; 
   }
```

donde `arrayObjetos` es el array original e `i` es el elemento dentro del array que deseas eliminar.

Este es otro metodo:

```
   private  static Object[]  remueveElement(Object[] arrayObjetos, int i) {
    Object[] nuevoArray = new Object[arrayObjetos.length - 1];
     if (i > 0){
           System.arraycopy(arrayObjetos, 0, nuevoArray, 0, i);
     }
     if (nuevoArray.length > i){
      System.arraycopy(arrayObjetos, i + 1, nuevoArray, i, nuevoArray.length - i);
     }
     return nuevoArray;
   }
```

---

#### Ejemplo para corroborar funcionamiento de los métodos sugeridos:

Usando cualquiera de los métodos puedes eliminar un elemento de tu arreglo de objetos, agrego un ejemplo de su uso, donde definimos un array de objetos de 10 elementos y deseamos eliminar el que se encuentra en el indice 3:

```
   //Creamos un array de 10 elementos 
   Object[] arrayOriginal = new Object[10];
    for( int i=0; i<10; i++ )
    arrayOriginal[i] = new Object();
    
     for( int i=0; i<arrayOriginal.length; i++ )
   System.out.println("array original elemento " + i + " :    " + arrayOriginal[i]);

   //eliminamos el elemento en el indice 3.
   Object[] arrayresultante = remueveElement(arrayOriginal, 3);
   
     for( int i=0; i<arrayresultante.length; i++ )
   System.out.println("array resultante elemento " + i + " :   " + arrayresultante[i]);
```

puedes observar que el elemento en el indice 3 fue eliminado del arreglo de objetos original:

```
array original elemento 0 :    java.lang.Object@7ea987ac
array original elemento 1 :    java.lang.Object@12a3a380
array original elemento 2 :    java.lang.Object@29453f44
array original elemento 3 :    java.lang.Object@5cad8086   //objeto a eliminar!.
array original elemento 4 :    java.lang.Object@6e0be858
array original elemento 5 :    java.lang.Object@61bbe9ba
array original elemento 6 :    java.lang.Object@610455d6
array original elemento 7 :    java.lang.Object@511d50c0
array original elemento 8 :    java.lang.Object@60e53b93
array original elemento 9 :    java.lang.Object@5e2de80c

array resultante elemento 0 :   java.lang.Object@7ea987ac
array resultante elemento 1 :   java.lang.Object@12a3a380
array resultante elemento 2 :   java.lang.Object@29453f44
array resultante elemento 3 :   java.lang.Object@6e0be858
array resultante elemento 4 :   java.lang.Object@61bbe9ba
array resultante elemento 5 :   java.lang.Object@610455d6
array resultante elemento 6 :   java.lang.Object@511d50c0
array resultante elemento 7 :   java.lang.Object@60e53b93
array resultante elemento 8 :   java.lang.Object@5e2de80c
```

Comment: Acaso el índice 3 no es el objeto "java.lang.Object@29453f44"? considerando que el siempre el índice inicial es 0 (el primero). Se presta para ambiguedades

Comment: @PatricioBonilla el elemento del Array con indice 3 es java.lang.Object@5cad8086 , como tu lo comentas, inicia desde 0 el primer elemento del Array.

Comment: @Elenasys estaba confundido. Tener el indice 3 no implica que sea el tercer elemento del arreglo. Gracias por la aclaración.

Comment: Ah hehe, no te preocupes amigo, saludos! :)

Answer (score 5):

El método para eliminar un elemento de un arreglo es encontrar la casilla que necesitas eliminar su contenido y copiar el contenido de las demás casillas a una casilla anterior.

Ejemplo:

```
public class EjemploEliminarDeArreglo {
    public boolean eliminar(int[] arreglo, int elemento) {
        boolean resultado = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
            if (arreglo[i] == elemento) {
                for (int j = i; j < arreglo.length - 1; j++) {
                    arreglo[j] = arreglo[j+1];
                }
                arreglo[arreglo.length - 1] = 0;
                resultado = true;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }

    public void ejemploEliminar(int[] arreglo, int numero) {
        //mencionaste no usar librerías externas de Java para
        //eliminar el elemento, pero no mencionaste
        //si no debían usarse para otras funciones como
        //mostrar su contenido
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arreglo));
        if (eliminar(arreglo, numero)) {
            System.out.println(
                String.format(
                    "Se eliminó %d. Ahora el arreglo es: %s",
                    numero, Arrays.toString(arreglo)));
        } else {
            System.out.println("El arreglo sigue intacto.");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //arreglo definido de manera estática
        int[] arreglo = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
        EjemploEliminarDeArreglo ejemplo = new EjemploEliminarDeArreglo();
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(otroArreglo));
        //eliminando los números 3, 10 y 4 del arreglo
        ejemplo.ejemploEliminar(arreglo, 3);
        ejemplo.ejemploEliminar(arreglo, 10);
        ejemplo.ejemploEliminar(arreglo, 4);

        //el mismo caso de antes pero asignamos los valores del arreglo desde un for
        int[] otroArreglo = new int[5];
        //solo a modo de demostración, imprimimos el contenido del arreglo
        //será algo como [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
        //porque eso es un arreglo de enteros vacío en Java
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(otroArreglo));
        //ahora, le asignamos elementos
        for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
            otroArreglo[i-1] = i;
        }
        //y lo volvemos a mostrar en la consola
        //ahora luce [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] como lucía `arreglo`
        //antes que le eliminaran sus datos
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(otroArreglo));
    }
}
```

---

En Java, un arreglo tiene una longitud que **no cambia**, denotada por el atributo `length`, por lo que al "eliminar" un elemento en realidad estás indicando que tu arreglo va a tener elementos vacíos. Esto es aceptable y normal en los arreglos.

Con esto en mente, cabe mencionar que las otras respuestas no explican realmente cómo eliminar un elemento de un arreglo, lo que explican es cómo crear un nuevo arreglo sin el elemento que quieres "eliminar". Esta es otra forma de solucionar el problema, pero no atiende la definición concreta de eliminar un elemento de un arreglo.

Claro, existe una clase llamada `ArrayList` que da la impresión de manejar un arreglo que crece dinámicamente, pero esto no es cierto. Viendo sus fuentes, lo que encontramos es que siempre mantiene un solo arreglo y la cantidad de elementos de este arreglo, lo que causa la sensación de que nuestro arreglo crece dinámicamente. Asimismo, si necesita soportar más elementos de los que tiene actualmente, lo que hará es:

- Crear un nuevo arreglo con un tamaño suficiente para soportar más elementos (usualmente esto es la longitud por 1.5).
- Copiar los elementos del arreglo actual al nuevo arreglo.
- Usar el nuevo arreglo para continuar almacenando información.

Comment: Una forma más eficiente de eliminar "in situ" es copiar el último elemento al que va a ser borrado. Aunque esto solo sirve si no hay que preservar el órden. Y se complica la cosa si pensamos que ya puede haber elementos en la última posición que pueden ser null. Con lo quizá mejor dejarlo como lo ha puesto Luiggi (+1).

Answer (score 3):

La forma más sencilla **(Sin usar clases ni Bibliotecas creadas por Java)**
es Recorrer el Array y verificar con un `if` la condición para eliminar un elemento. Utilizariamos un Arreglo Temporal de Objetos  para ir añadiendo los que no cumplen con la condición

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Object[] array = new Object[]{"A","B","C"};/*Array en este caso de String */
    Object[] temp = new Object[array.length]; /* Temporal Array*/
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         /* El String.valueOf(array[i]) es para convertir a 
           String el Objecto  comparamos si no es igual a b ,si se cumple 
           lo agregamos al temporal*/
         if(!String.valueOf(array[i]).toLowerCase().equals("b"))
        {
            temp[i]=array[i]; /* Agregamos al Arreglo Temporal */
        }
    }

    /* Imprimir */
    for (Object temp1 : temp) {
        System.out.println((temp1!=null)?String.valueOf(temp1):"");
    }

}
```

Si se da la opción de usar Clases podría usar [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) ya que esta no tiene un tamaño fijo como tienen lo Arreglos... puede  tener algo así para eliminar un Elemento

```
/* Convertimos el Array a Un ArrayList  aunque se podría crear desde el 
     inicio y agregar con lista.add("A"); lista.add("B"); etc*/
ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array)); 
lista.remove("A"); /* Eliminamos A*/
```

> Podrías tomar la decisión de usar bibliotecas o clases que haría este trabajo mucho mejor , quizá hasta en una sola línea

Answer (score 1):

Dependiendo de si quieres tener nulls o no en tu array puedes proceder de dos formas. Si no te importan los nulls en tu arreglo, puedes simplemente recorrerlo cuando encuentres ese objecto seteas la casilla en null. Si no quieres tener nulls puedes usar un array auxiliar. También puedes querer decidir si borras el primer objeto que encuentres que sea igual, o borras todos los que sean iguales al que quieres borrar.
Te dejo un código con todos estos casos:

```
public class BorrarObjetosDeArreglos {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object[] array = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2 };
    BorrarObjetosDeArreglos arrayUtils = new BorrarObjetosDeArreglos();

    // Borra el primer elemento que encuentra
    arrayUtils.borrarUno(2, array);
    // imprime [0]=1,a[1]=null,a[2]=3,a[3]=4,a[4]=2
    arrayUtils.imprimirArreglo(array, "a");

    // Vuelvo a crear el arreglo porque el anterior me quedo con el 2
    // borrado
    array = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2 };

    // Borra todos los que encuentra
    arrayUtils.borrarTodos(2, array);
    // imprime a[0]=1,a[1]=null,a[2]=3,a[3]=4,a[4]=null
    arrayUtils.imprimirArreglo(array, "a");

    array = new Object[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 2 };
    Object[] arrayNuevo = arrayUtils.borrarTodoCrearArrayNuevo(2, array);

    // imprime a[0]=1,a[1]=3,a[2]=4
    arrayUtils.imprimirArreglo(arrayNuevo, "a");
}

public void imprimirArreglo(Object[] arreglo, String nombreArreglo) {
    StringBuffer sf = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length - 1; i++) {
        sf.append(nombreArreglo + "[" + i + "]=" + arreglo[i] + ",");
    }
    sf.append(nombreArreglo + "[" + (arreglo.length - 1) + "]=" + arreglo[arreglo.length - 1]);
    System.out.println(sf.toString());

}

public void borrarUno(Object aBorrar, Object[] arreglo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        Object objetoEnArray = arreglo[i];
        if (objetoEnArray != null && objetoEnArray.equals(aBorrar)) {
            arreglo[i] = null;
            return;
        }
    }
}

public void borrarTodos(Object aBorrar, Object[] arreglo) {
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        Object objetoEnArray = arreglo[i];
        if (objetoEnArray != null && objetoEnArray.equals(aBorrar)) {
            arreglo[i] = null;
        }
    }
}

public Object[] borrarTodoCrearArrayNuevo(Object aBorrar, Object[] arreglo) {
    Integer cantidadBorrados = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
        Object objetoEnArray = arreglo[i];
        if (objetoEnArray != null && objetoEnArray.equals(aBorrar)) {
            arreglo[i] = null;
            cantidadBorrados++;             
        }
    }
    Object[] arregloNuevo = new Object[arreglo.length - cantidadBorrados];
    Integer indiceEnArrayNuevo = 0;
    for (Object objetoEnArrayViejo : arreglo) {
        if (objetoEnArrayViejo != null) {
            arregloNuevo[indiceEnArrayNuevo] = objetoEnArrayViejo;
            indiceEnArrayNuevo++;
        }
    }
    return arregloNuevo;
}
```

}

Comment: Muy completo. Yo el caso de ´borrarTodoCrearArrayNuevo´ lo haría respetando el arreglo original; sin hacer modificaciones en él. En cualquier caso +1.

Answer (score 1):

si es arreglo puedes dejarlo en null ejemplo

```
arreglo[indice]=null;
```

si es ArrayList

```
arreglo.remove(indice);
```

este recibe por parametro  indice o objeto a eliminar