# Eliminación de posición de array

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un curso de java y me han puesto un ejercicio que sinceramente no entiendo. Ahora entenderéis vosotros porque no entiendo este ejercicio. Si alguien conoce la solución que la ponga por favor y de una explicación del porqué. Quiero recordar que solo puedes modificar codigo donde se hallen las "XXXXXXX", no puedes agregar lineas nuevas:

**Dado el siguiente código en Java, completa las expresiones que faltan del método eliminarElemento, para que elimine el elemento del array que se le pasa como parámetro. Cuando se elimine un elemento hay que desplazar los demás, para no dejar un hueco.**

```
   static int []elementos = new int[15];
   private static int totalElementos=elementos.length;

   public static void eliminarElemento(int elemento)
   {
      int posicion = 0;
      int i;
      if (totalElementos>0){
        while (XXXXXXXXX)
           posicion++;
        if (posicion<totalElementos){
          for(XXXXXXXXXXXXXX) {
             elementos[i]=elementos[i+1];
          }
         totalElementos--; 
        } 
      }
   }
}
```

**Edit: Quería agregar unos argumentos que tengáis en cuenta:**

- En el curso, evidentemente he solicitado al profesor, reiteradas veces, que debido a que no entiendo el ejercicio por favor mándeme la solución con una explicación para poder entender cual es el correcto funcionamiento así de cara a futuros practicas sabré proceder correctamente. El profesor se niega, a mi solicitud.
- Conozco los arrays, se que cuanto instancias un array se guarda ese espacio de memoria secuencial y estático. Es decir, una vez ubicada cuantas posiciones de memoria va a tener se reserva dicho espacio y no puede ser modificado, para eso tenemos lo que llamamos listas, que son posiciones de memoria dinámicas que nos permiten agregar y eliminar elementos a nuestro antojo. Para mi, este ejercicio carece de sentido desde el minuto uno. En un array no se puede eliminar una posicion, como mucho, puedes anularla (pasar a 0 o null) y ya derivarla al final de dicho array, pero por más que anules la posicion, el elemento y su posicion de almacenamiento van a seguir existiendo, te guste o no, pues es el funcionamiento que le dieron en su diseño a dicho elemento.

Comment: Que has intentado hasta el momento, ya realizaste alguna investigación previa. Te dejo los siguientes enlaces para que mejores tu pregunta. Evita los negativos e incluso el cierre de tu pregunta. [¿has intentado algo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/), [¿Qué has investigado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878). De paso Visita la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: ***1ro:*** la mitad de tu pregunta esta fuera de contexto para lo que es stackoverflow. ***2do:*** recordarte que no puedes llegar exigiendo que te hagan la tarea. ***3ro:*** La asignación que te dejaron esta super fácil, es más, si hubiera tenidos un poco menos de prepotencia ya alguien te hubiera ayudado. ***4to:*** Investiga cual es la diferencia de un while con llaves y sin llaves y como recorrer un array con un for. Con esto deberías de solucionar tu tarea, y hay algo que se llama pruebas de escritorio.

Comment: Por cierto, la asignación no trata de eliminar explícitamente una posición del array, si no, de desplazar los valores por cada supuesto índice a eliminar. ***Algo que esta explícito en la descripción del problema***. No confundas: eliminar una posición del array a desplazar los valores del array.

Comment: Hola, veo que has tenido algunos mal entendidos con la forma en que funciona el sitio. Yo también fui novato una vez, pero cuando yo fui novato no existía este sitio, de hecho apenas existía Internet, por lo tanto me tocó sudármela como la mayoría de los buenos programadores. Dicho esto, entendemos tu dificultad. Deseas que te digan qué debes colocar en lugar de las ***XXXXXXX***, y que además te expliquen el porqué. La verdad, si en mi época el profesor hubiese puesto un ejercicio así, hubiéramos sido muy felices. No lo tomes a mal, es solo una opinión.

Comment: Lo que te sugiero que hagas es intentarlo tu mismo, reemplazar las ***XXXXX*** por algo y ver qué sucede. Así se programaba antes y así se hará siempre. Ensayo y error, y vuelta a empezar. De esa forma entenderás el proceso y aprenderás del mismo. Ya te han dado una respuesta, con detalle sobre lo que se puede hacer, debes aplicar eso en tu ejercicio. Y si tienes una dificultad, vienes por aquí y la planteas, explicando lo que hiciste y el error que obtienes. Seguramente así tu pregunta será mejor recibida. Saludos

Comment: Si tu fuente de confusión proviene de lo que explicas en la tercera observación (que no entiendes cómo se puede eliminar un elemento de un array), en cierto sentido tienes razón. El enunciado debe entenderse como que _el valor_ que estaba allí guardado "desaparece" en un cierto sentido. Un ejemplo. El array tiene inicialmente los datos `[0,2,4,6,8]` y `total_elementos` vale 5. Entonces haces una llamada a `eliminar(1)`. A la vuelta, `total_elementos` debe valer 4, y los 4 primeros elementos de ese array han de ser `[0,4,6,8]` (sí, aún habrá un quinto elemento pero su valor ya no importa).

Comment: Hola @IsmaelGarciaMartin Recuerda que en el sitio tenemos un [Código de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/conduct), te sugiero evitar realizar comentarios que no tengan cabida en el sitio, recuerda que la comunidad trata de ayudarte a mejorar tu pregunta para poder ayudarte, tu pregunta fue reportada por contener contenido "irrespetuoso o abusivo", te sugiero editarla y quitar comentarios que puedan ser sensibles para los usuarios, no te desesperes por favor solo trata de mejorar tu pregunta con información que te sugieren!, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

te dejare varias respuestas en caso de que te sirva alguna:

Respuesta 1:
Para Eliminar el valor de un array usamos el removeIndex
Ejemplo 1:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] valores = {"uno", "dos", "tres"};

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valores));

        removeIndex(valores, 0);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(valores));
    }

    private static void removeIndex(String[] array, int index) {
        int i = index;
        for (; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }
        array[i] = null;
    }
```

Ejemplo2:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class RemoveExample {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       //String ArrayList
       ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<String>();
       al.add("AB");
       al.add("CD");
       al.add("EF");
       al.add("GH");
       al.add("AB");
       al.add("YZ");
       System.out.println("ArrayList before remove:");
       for(String var: al){
            System.out.println(var);
       }
       //Removing 1st element
       al.remove(0);
       //Removing 3rd element from the remaining list
       al.remove(2);
       //Removing 4th element from the remaining list
       al.remove(2);
       System.out.println("ArrayList After remove:");
       for(String var2: al){
             System.out.println(var2);
       }
    }
}
```

**output:
ArrayList before remove:**

1. AB
2. CD
3. EF
4. GH
5. AB
6. YZ

**ArrayList After remove:**

1. CD
2. EF
3. YZ

Respuesta 2:
Modificar el ciclo:
ejemplo:
for(int i=a.size()-1; i>=0; i--){
...
}

> length is constant which is used to find out the array storing
>   capacity not the number of elements in the array
>
> Example:
>
> int a[] = new int[5] a.length always returns 5 which is called the
>   capacity of an array, so length always returns the CAPACITY. but
>
> "number of elements in the array is called size"
>
> Example:
>
> int a[] = new int[5] a[0] = 10 Will result in a.size = 1 and a.length
>   = 5.
>
> size() works with collection, length works with arrays in java

Ademas, te dejare un link que puede ser de utilidad, [Pincha Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26024/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-un-objeto-de-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-java)

Comment: Te agradezco enormemente que hayas sacado tiempo a contestar mi duda, pero debo recordarte, con gran pesar, lo que escribí con anterioridad:

"Si alguien conoce la solución que la ponga por favor y de una explicación del porqué. Quiero recordar que solo puedes modificar codigo donde se hallen las "XXXXXXX", no puedes agregar lineas nuevas"

Tu respuesta no entra dentro de los parámetros establecidos en el ejercicio.
Gracias de todas formas por tu apoyo.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución @Roderick recuerda responder preguntas que se realizan conforme a lo dictado en el [help], particularmente [ask], ya que de otra forma puede ser que lo que respondas no sea en realidad lo que necesita el OP, saludos.