# Como puedo borrar información guardada en un arreglo?

Tags: java

Este es mi código
que tal, quisiera añadir una función la cual me permita borrar información que se guardo en el arreglo, el programa da solución a un sistema que requiere un restaurante, la cual el encargado ingresa los datos del cliente en el mismo, el encargado puede ver las reservaciones mediante un menú pero este también requiere poder eliminar esta información capturada

Esta es la función principal, la cual muestra el menú y pide el numero de veses que se desea capturar la información del cliente:

```
package productoint;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ProductoInt {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
       int opcion;
       int numcliente;




Cliente client [];

numcliente = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Numero de clientes")); //tamaño del arreglo

client = new Cliente[numcliente]; //arreglo

boolean salir = false;

while(!salir){

       opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Selecciona una opción"
               + "\nTeclea 1 para capturar la información del cliente"
               + "\nTeclea 2 para mostrar la info. del cliente"
               + "\n Presiona 3 para salir."));
       switch(opcion){
           case 1:
               for(int i=0; i<numcliente; i++){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Cliente no."+(i+1)+":");
                   client[i] = new Cliente();
                   client[i].datos_client(); //parte donde guarda la información
               }
               break;
           case 2:
               for(int i=0; i<numcliente; i++){
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente no."+(i+1)+":");
                   client[i].imprim_datos();
               }
               break;
           case 3:

               break;
           case 4:
               salir = true;
               break;
       }

}

    }


}
```

Esta es la clase la cual pide los datos a capturar del cliente

```
package productoint;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Cliente {
    String nombre ="";
    String apellido="";
    int num_acom=0;
    int dia=0;
    String mes="";
    int anio=0;
    public void datos_client(){
       nombre = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingresa el nombre");
       apellido = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el apellido");
       num_acom = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa la cantidad de acompañantes"));
       dia = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el dia(numero)"));
       mes = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el mes");
       anio = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el año"));
    }
    public void imprim_datos(){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nombre:" +nombre
        +"\nApellido:" +apellido
        +"\nNumero de acompañantes:" +num_acom
        +"\nDia:" +dia
        +"\nMes:" +mes
        +"\nAño:" +anio);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y a leer [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Las preguntas con solo código, sin una explicación de lo que quieres y lo que has intentado, tienen realmente pocas probabilidades de obtener respuestas. Un saludo.

Comment: si quieres revisa el siguiente enlace: [https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26024/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-un-objeto-de-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26024/c%C3%B3mo-eliminar-un-objeto-de-un-arreglo-de-objetos-en-java) ahi te dan comentarios. Otra forma es utilizar una lista con la clase java.util.List que es mas dinámica para trabajar a diferencia del arreglo, y cuenta con varios métodos muy útiles

Comment: No has pensado en utilizar un arrayList? o quieres que sea solamente con un array de tipo Client ? ya que de igualmenera puede utilizar un ArrayList de tipo cliente para almacenar la informacion completa del cliente en un arrayList

Answer (score 0):

Puedes alianzarlo a una base de datos local y simplemente manejar un id a cada nuevo registro, asi puedes escoger que quieres eliminar por su id.

```
public void borrarDatos(String codigo) {

    String codigo= codigo;
    String borraSql = "DELETE FROM baseDatos WHERE codigo =?";
    try {
        PreparedStatement inst =
        conexion.getConnection().prepareStatement(borraSql);
        inst.setString(1, codigo);
        inst.executeUpdate();
    } catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println(e);
       }
       catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
            }
}
```

He implementas este método.

Comment: Esto no es respuesta a lo que se pide

Answer (score 0):

Una forma de dar solución a lo que quieres realizar podria ser con `ArrayList`

1 Creamos un `ArrayList` de tipo Cliente

`ArrayList<Client> listaClientes = new ArrayList<>();`

2 En la inserción de un nuevo elemento creamos un objeto para después ingresarlo al `ArrayList`

```
case 1:
             for (int i = 0; i < numcliente; i++) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente no." + (i + 1) + ":");
                        Client cliente = new Client();
                        cliente.datos_client();
                        listaClientes.add(cliente);
                    }
                    break;
```

para visualizar los clientes quedaría de la siguiente forma

```
case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.size(); i++) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente no." + (i + 1) + ":");
                    //client[i].imprim_datos();
                    listaClientes.get(i).imprim_datos();
                }
                break;
```

### Para eliminar un cliente seria de la siguiente forma

```
case 3:
                int numeroCliente =Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingrese el numero del cliente a eliminar "));
                listaClientes.remove(numeroCliente-1);
                break;
```

Comment: Tampoco es respuesta a la pregunta. El no pregunta sobre List, sino cómo eliminar un objeto de un Array.